# Skip iteration in nested AngularJS Repeat

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

A bit of background first:

I am creating a web app that will display multiple reports onscreen simultaneously in a table. The way the reports are stored are in their own separate tables. As of now the angular app loops through the loaded reports and places them like so:

```
Group 1
  Report1 Val1 Val2 Val3...
  Report2 Val1 Val2 Val3...
  ReportN Val1 Val2 Val3...
Group 2
  Report1 Val1 Val2 Val3...
  Report2 Val1 Val2 Val3...
  ReportN Val1 Val2 Val3...
Group N
  Report1 Val1 Val2 Val3...
  Report2 Val1 Val2 Val3...
  ReportN Val1 Val2 Val3...
```

The problem I am getting is that some of the reports will lack a row for a given grouping, which makes the overall table mismatched in the end. What I am wondering is if there is a means within ngRepeat to more or less skip a row while looping in order to only place the values in their respective group?

The only solution I can think of for this is to just manually insert blank rows in the other reports so that they will always have matching dimensions, but if angular can help facilitate this it would be better, and thus far Google has yielded no results.

For reference, this is my current table generating code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="row in loadedReports[0].data" ng-if="loadedReports.length > 1 && !loadedReports[1].empty">
        <td ng-repeat="count in row track by $index" class="title" ng-show="$index > 12 - range || $first"><span ng-show="$first">{{ row[0] }}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="report in $parent.loadedReports" ng-repeat-end>
        <td ng-repeat="value in report.data[$parent.$index] track by $index" ng-class="{'title': $first && $parent.$parent.$last && ($parent.$parent.loadedReports.length === 1 || $parent.$parent.loadedReports[1].empty)}" ng-show="$index > 12 - range || $first">
            <span ng-if="$parent.$parent.loadedReports.length > 1 && !$parent.$parent.loadedReports[1].empty && $first">{{ report.name }}</span>
            <span ng-if="($parent.$parent.loadedReports.length === 1 && $first) || ($parent.$parent.loadedReports[1].empty) || $index > 12 - range">{{ value | numberFormat : report.dataType }}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Edit for clarification of code:

- range is simply a control on screen that will allow up to 13 of the stored values in a row to be displayed, minimally 2.
- data is a 2 dimensional array that contains a row for each group in the data set

Comment: How about a custom filter that returns `false` if the row is not complete?

Comment: @floribon won't the filter just make that index value return blank though? I need the iteration to in effect be suspended for that specific row, rather than just showing nothing as the iteration on the next row would still be tied to the index in the array

Comment: No, filter is applied first and then `ng-repeat` loops on the results: if only 5 items are filtered, `$index` will go from 0 to 5 on these items.

Comment: That is some really ugly looking logic mixed into he view. Now you want to add more. Seems like time to move the filtering to the controller or a custom filter